# Formatting y axis datetime.time values as "%H:%M:%S.%f"

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

I am trying to format Y-axis datetime.time values as %H:%M:%S.%f

This code:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=(20, 5), dpi=150)
axes.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%m-%Y'))

#axes.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S.%f'))

axes.plot_date(test_df["date"],test_df["time"],ydate=True)

plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
```

gives

[image: output1]

When I uncomment `axes.yaxis.set_major_formatter`, the graph shows zeros on the Y-axis:

[image: output2]

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Your code works for me

Comment: So you do see other times than zeros?

Comment: Yes, as you expected. if you want I can post df, code and plot

Comment: which version(s) are you using?

Comment: yes please, so I can test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested i post the df and code I used with its output.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': ['7:30', '8:30', '7:30','10:30','11:30'], 'date': ['2018-10-01', '2018-10-02', '2018-10-03', '2018-10-04','2018-10-05']})

import matplotlib.dates as mdates
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%H:%M') 
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1)
axes.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%m-%Y'))
axes.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S'))
axes.plot_date(df["date"],df["time"],ydate=True)
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Tx, tried your code and it gives an error:

ValueError: DateFormatter found a value of x=0, which is an illegal date.  This usually occurs because you have not informed the axis that it is plotting dates, e.g., with ax.xaxis_date()

Comment: if you add after the df: `df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%H:%M')`
`df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')` ?

Comment: Probably the versions then

Comment: Tx for your help, I'll explicitly convert datetime.time to timestamp to get it working